# Find and update non duplicated record based on one of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to find all the non duplicated records and update one of the column.

Ex.

```
Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | Col_5
A     | AA    | BB    | 1     | 
A     | AB    | BC    | 2     |
A     | AC    | BD    | 3     |
B     | BB    | CC    | 1     |
B     | BB    | CC    | 2     |
C     | CC    | DD    | 1     |
```

My query has to group by Col_1, and I want to find out not unique record based on Col_2 and Col3 and then update the Col_5.

Basically output should be as below,

```
Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | Col_5
A     | AA    | BB    | 1     | 1
A     | AB    | BC    | 2     | 1
A     | AC    | BD    | 3     | 1
B     | BB    | CC    | 1     | 0
B     | BB    | CC    | 2     | 0
C     | CC    | DD    | 1     | 0
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I achieve this? This is a large database, so performance is also a key factor.

Thanks heaps,

Comment: could you please provide any query you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unable to write something which does what I want. thanks

Comment: Why the last row is not updated?

Comment: What means the values 1 and 0 into col_5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty ways to do it. This solution comes from postgres for which I have access to, but I bet it will be working also on tsql as should have common syntax.

```
;WITH
cte_1 AS (
    SELECT col_1 FROM some_table GROUP BY col_1 HAVING count(*) > 1
),
cte_2 AS (
    SELECT col_1 FROM some_table GROUP BY col_1, col_2, col_3 HAVING count(*) > 1
),
cte_3 AS (
    SELECT cte_1.col_1 FROM cte_1
    LEFT JOIN cte_2 ON cte_1.col_1 = cte_2.col_1
    WHERE cte_2.col_1 IS NULL
)
UPDATE some_table SET col_5 = 1
FROM cte_3 WHERE cte_3.col_1 = some_table.col_1;
```

So, what happens above?

1. First we build three [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) semi-tables which allow us to split logic into smaller parts:

   - `cte_1` which extracts rows which can have multiple `col2` and `col_3` rows
   - `cte_2` which selects those which have non-unique `col_2` and `col_3`
   - `cte_3` which returns those `col_1` which have unique `col_2` and `col_3` just by `LEFT JOIN`
2. Using the last `cte_3` structure we are able to update `some_table` correctly

I assume that your table is called `some_table` here. If you're worring about a performance you should provide some primary key here and also it would be good to have indexes on `col_2` and `col_3` (standalone but it may help if those would be composite on `(col_1, col_2)` and so on).

Also you may want to move it from **CTE** to use **temporary** tables (which could be also indexed to gain efficiency.

Please also note that this query works fine with your example but without real data it may be just guessing. I mean that what will happen when you would have for `col_1`=A some unique and non-uniqe `col_2` in the same time?

But I believe it's good point to start.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, as you said, it did not work when col_1 have some unique and non-unique. So I updated the CTE as below.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH
cte_1 AS (
    SELECT col_1, count(*) as items FROM some_table GROUP BY col_1 HAVING count(*) > 1
),
cte_2 AS (
    SELECT col_1, count(*) as items FROM some_table GROUP BY col_1, col_2, col_3 HAVING count(*) > 1
),
cte_3 AS (
    SELECT cte_1.col_1 FROM cte_1
    LEFT JOIN cte_2 ON cte_1.col_1 = cte_2.col_1
    WHERE cte_2.col_1 IS NULL OR cte_1.items > cte_2.items
    GROUP BY cte_1.col_1
)
UPDATE some_table SET col_5 = 1
FROM cte_3 WHERE cte_3.col_1 = some_table.col_1;
```